# Image.FromStream mono memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, mono

I believe I have stumbled across a memory leak in Mono 4.6 and 4.8 using the Image.FromStream call. Below is a code snippet that can be used to reproduce the problem. I have tested this in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Mono 4.6 and 4.8.

I have posted a Visual Studio/MonoDevelop solution and project (in a tar.gz file) here: [BitmapTest.tar.gz](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/file/n4670327/BitmapTest.gz). After extracting BitmapTest.gz, rename BitmapTest to BitmapTest.tar.gz so you can extract the code.

This project is a simple Winforms app that runs the code below.

Is there a work around, or something I am not considering?

EDIT:
If I use

```
using (Bitmap srcBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(_file_name))
```

instead of

```
using (Bitmap srcBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms))
```

It works. The problem seems to be in Image.FromStream.

```
// populate our byte[] array with a .BMP file
ImageConverter convert = new ImageConverter();
private byte[] _sourceArray = (byte[])convert.ConvertTo(Image.FromFile(filename_string), typeof(byte[]));

// put the following code in a loop
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(_sourceArray))
{
     System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("First memory stream created OK size: " + ms.Capacity.ToString());
     using (Bitmap srcBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms))
     {
          System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("First Bitmap created OK size: " + srcBitmap.Size.ToString());
     }
}

// If GC is called then the memory climbs slower
if (_forceGC) {
     GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
     GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: If this is reproducible, consider filing a bug at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: I filed a BUG report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54149